# Как сделать, чтобы скрипт работал на одной странице?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте.

Возникла следующая проблема: нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора на картинку, она менялась на другую. Это нужно сделать в статической странице на DLE. Всего 2 фото. Читал что надо применить hover, но что-то не получается (может не туда вставляю, надо именно на определённую страницу вставить). Пробовал применить "JavaScript", всё работает, но только на первой странице, а как перенести её в статическую, не могу понять. (Прописывал ява скрипт в head и в body, поэтому и работает на первой странице, а когда пытался вставить в новость или в статическую страницу, ничего не происходило или вообще ничего не было видно). Необходимо вставить только на одну определенную страницу.

Объясните пожалуйста, если можно очень подробно, что и куда надо вставить. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А можно более адекватно составлять вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Пример с hover:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hover</title>
<style>
 /* картинки в папке в корне сайта nyanyanya.nya/images/nya.ico */
 #myimage {
     /* http://nya.sh/favicon.ico */
     background:url(images/nya.ico) no-repeat 0px 0px;
     width: 16px;
     height: 16px;
 }
 #myimage:hover {
     /* http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/favicon.ico */
     background:url(images/hash.ico) no-repeat 0px 0px;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="myimage" />
</body>
</html>
```

Пример с javascript:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="myimage" src="images/nya.ico"
                      onmouseover="this.src='images/hash.ico';"
                      onmouseout="this.src='images/nya.ico';" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Прописывал ява скрипт в head и в body,
> поэтому и работает на первой странице,
> а когда пытался вставить в новость или
> в статическую страницу, ничего не
> происходило или вообще ничего не было
> видно

Вы через добавление новости`/`статической страницы скрипт вставляли?
Если да, то DLE вырезает скрипты, поэтому у вас ничего и не работало.

Вариант 1

Вставить скрипт в статическую страницу напрямую через phpmyadmin

Вариант 2

В саму статическую страницу вставляем

```
<img id="myimage" src="images/image1.jpg" />
```

И в шаблоне main.tpl перед закрывающим элементом `</body>` дописываем

```
[aviable=static]<script>
document.getElementById('myimage').onmouseover = function() {
     this.src='image2.jpg';
}
document.getElementById('myimage').onmouseout = function() {
     this.src='image1.jpg';
}
</script>[/aviable]
```

Answer (score 0):

На каждой статической странице вставляйте:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/myscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Значение src  должно указывать путь к папке, где находится скрипт, например, `/JS/myscript.js`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но что то у меня не получается. Наверное не то делаю. Кто может объяснить как это сделать (объяснить досконально), как разместить меняющуюся фотку на определённой странице (нужно именно на статистической) и сколько будет стоить ваше объяснение (только в разумных пределах).

Comment: А можно ссылку на ваш сайт или хотя бы код той страницы, на которую вы хотите вставить эту меняющуюся фотку.

Comment: http://fotozov.ru/index.php?do=static&page=uslugi

Answer (score 0):

1. Заходите в панель phpMyAdmin
2. Слева в меню выбираете `dle_static`
3. У вас появится список ваших страниц выбираете и нажимаете на карандашик, то есть "Изменить"
4. Там появится панелька для редактирования кода страницы , вставляете туда скрипт и все нажимаете ок или сохранить и все.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть легче будет использование jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Vasya попробуй так.
В main.tpl добавь после {AJAX} вот этот код

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.img_replace img:eq(1)').css({display: 'none'});  
    var img0 = $('.img_replace img:eq(0)').attr('src');
    var img1 = $('.img_replace img:eq(1)').attr('src');  
    $('.img_replace img:eq(0)').hover(
      function(){$(this).attr({src:img1});},
      function(){$(this).attr({src:img0});}
    );  
  });
  </script>
```

А в коде статичесткой страницы заключай две картинки в тег `<p class="img_replace">...</p>` тогда вторая картинка будет исчезать а при наведении на первую появляться на её месте.
PS. код я конечно извращённо написал )))

Comment: и кстати этот вариант будет работать по всему сайту и в новостях тоже

Answer (score 0):

Переписал немного

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.img_replace img:odd').css({display: 'none'});  
        var img0; var img1;

    $('.img_replace img').hover(
            function(){
                    img0 = $(this).attr('src');
                    img1 = $(this).next('img').attr('src');
                    $(this).attr({src:img1});
                    },
            function(){
                    $(this).attr({src:img0});
                    }
    );  
 });
</script>
```

Ну и соответственно картинки должны выглядеть типа

```
<p class="img_replace">
    <img src="ppp_image.jpg"/><img  src="ppp_image2.jpg"/>
</p>
............тут например текст .............
<p class="img_replace">
    <img src="lll_image.jpg"/><img  src="lll_image2.jpg"/>
</p>
```

Замена картинок будет работать во всех местах. И не важно сколько пар картинок стоит

Answer (score 0):

Странно что ответа с css нет, наверное слишком давно задан вопрос:

http://jsfiddle.net/o8yyxqrx/

```
.hasImage {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/320x200&text=1');
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
}
.hasImage:hover {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/320x200&text=2');
}
```

```
<div class="hasImage"></div>
```